# Does a function that returns a constant work slower than a void function?

Tags: c++, performance

Simplest example to highlight the difference:

```
int foo()
{
   doSomething();
   return 0;
}

void bar()
{
   doSomething();
   return;
}

int main()
{
   foo();
   bar();
}
```

Is `bar` faster than `foo`, and why?

Comment: There are many other things in programming that will affect the performance more than this bit of difference.

Comment: What made you think that?

Comment: Measure it and see? And remember to use the phrase "within the bounds of experimental error"...

Comment: The only time you may notice a return value hit is if the return is a structure of some size that is passed on the stack, and teh function is called a gazillion times, and the compiler can't inline it away.

Comment: Thank you all! So from what I understand, word-sized (correct?) types can be returned for practically no performance penalty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

void would be..but still it would be negligible.

The return value in the system is passed via the eax register on x86.
In most systems it is just a push into a register then perhaps creating the object when returns to the calling function. and since returning something like this would just post a 0 to eax which would prob be one less assembly command as perhaps the void will not call that and will not need to assign the int when it returns to the calling function.

Either way, this will not improve your performance of any application you write. If you have performance issues, look else where :)

Comment: I dunno, my ARM system doesn't have an EAX register :) - very system dependent answer here.

Comment: Sorry I was assuming a x86, still it will have very little if any significance..

Answer (score 16):

This is such a micro optimization that you should *never* have to even consider it. Yet the usual caveats when talking about performance:

- measure
- measure again
- change something
- measure
- make sure that you understand what you are measuring and why the change had an effect
- change it again a bit more with the new understanding and check whether the premise holds

As of the particular case of returning a small object (something that fits in a register), the cost is going to be negligible, basically a load into a register in most architectures.

Comment: `+1` for "make sure that you understand what you are measuring" :)

Comment: Wow - no biscuit for you on this one.  You've got enough already though I guess :)